# How to generate .vb files from ProtoGen.exe

Tags: vb.net, protocol-buffers, protogen

Please is there a switch in ProtoGen.exe to generate .vb files?

Generating the .cs files first then code converting is super tedious...

thanks!

Comment: Is this protobuf-net? Or protobuf-csharp-port? I have this hunch both called their generation tool "protogen"

Comment: i am trying to use your latest version Marc. I cannot Locate protogen in the download from Nuget: protobuf-net.2.0.0.668

Comment: @MarcGravell I am trying to use your latest version. I cannot Locate protogen in the download from Nuget: protobuf-net.2.0.0.668. I have been using and old version from some project which only supports .net 2.0. Please where can I locate your latest version of your protogen tool? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've found the required ProtoGen source and recompiled it for .Net45 it's in your old V1 repo, seems you have not revisited it in V2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is protobuf-net, then IIRC the `-t` switch selects the language - so probably `-t:vb`. This then resolves to `vb.xslt`. If unsure, `-?` or `-h` should show usage.

Comment: Thanks, but please where can i locate the latest version of your ProtoGen tool? its not included with the nuget Package, also I would like the generated .vb files to have just Public Property Name without the Get/Set coding and private _name field. This should be possible with .Net 4.0+ yes?

Comment: @Charles0 if the google download is still there: it is in that. Otherwise I'll need to repackage it. Re get/set: would need an edit to the vb.xslt